# Testing constructors in Go

Tags: unit-testing, testing, go

How I can test my `NewClient` constructor for my `Client` struct ?

```
package busybus

import (
    "bufio"
    "net"
)

type Client struct {
    counter  integer
    conn     net.Conn
    bufin    *bufio.Reader
    bufout   *bufio.Writer
    messages chan string
    state    string
}

func NewClient(conn net.Conn, messages chan string) *Client {
    return &Client{
        counter:  0,
        conn:     conn,
        bufin:    bufio.NewReader(conn),
        bufout:   bufio.NewWriter(conn),
        messages: messages,
        state:    "waiting",

    }
}
```

I tried some testing like this:

```
package busybus

import (
    "net"
    "testing"
)

func TestNewClient(t *testing.T) {
    ln, _ := net.Listen("tcp", ":65535")
    conn, _ := ln.Accept()
    messages := make(chan string)

    client := NewClient(conn, messages)
    if client.conn != conn {
        t.Errorf("NewClient(%q, %q).conn == %q, want %q", conn, messages, client.conn, conn)
    }
}
```

But this hangs during the test runs due to `ln.Accept`, it seems a totally wrong approach anyway... any suggestion how I can test this constructor ?

Answer (score 8):

Some code is so short and simple that ensuring that the test is correct is more complicated than ensuring that the code itself is correct. 
Your constructor is such code.

What I would do is either not test it at all, or just call it (using some dummy implementation of `net.Conn`) to ensure that it doesn't blow up in smoke when called (therefore called a smoke test).

Later you can test it as part of a bigger test (integration test), where you have a real server to connect to, and which uses your client struct to talk to it.

If you ever find a bug that is due to this constructor, then first add a test that demonstrates the problem, then fix it. Then you will have your test :-)

A test should check that the constructor "works as intended". Checking the value of `client.conn` is hardly checking any intended behavior, as the value of an unexported field is not behavior. It just checks HOW the struct and constructor is implemented, not WHAT it implements. Test the what, not the how.

By the way, you could maybe embed a *ReadWriter in your client.

```
client.buf = bufio.NewReadWriter(...)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion with the readwriter. Besides that i disagree. Of course this is a simple constructor which is not even necessary due to it simplicity,  but when I have some more complicated initialisation process I want check it right in the first place and not search later why my acceptance tests are failing. You wrote about a dummy connection, did you mean simply satisfying the net.Conn interface?

Comment: @astropanic: You wrote "but when I have some more complicated initialisation process": Currently you don't have it. Why bother now with something which probably never happens? Your constructor just returns a filled struct. Just test that. No need to be obsessive in your tests.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @bjarke-ebert said.

There are no constructors in Go, they are just normal functions. Test them as you would test any other function. If a function is too complex to test then probably there is a way to change the design to make it more testable.

Also from my experience tests that check internal details of implementation too much (like the test from the question) are very hard to maintain as they constantly need to be updated.

Comment: is a constructor not a normal function as well ? What are you suggesting instead of my function to initialize the struct ? Suppose I have some code where I need to initialise more of such client structs. I think without this function I will later have more code to rewrite when the functionality will need a change ? I saw this pattern plenty of times in different Golang projects, and read it is a common practice to use New or NewType, maybe I'm wrong (still learning Go), I'm open for suggestions, thx

Comment: Your question explicitly asks how to test constructors. I just made a point that you should test them as any other functions. Having `NewClient` function as in the example you provided makes perfect sense.

Comment: To elaborate a bit more: `NewClient` function is ok. But testing that conn field is initialized by NewClient doesn't make any sense as it should already be tested indirectly by other tests. Tests do not come for free. You need to write them, keep them up to date, they add to the test suite execution time, etc.